# Consuming Web Api method with ajax call in word web office add ins .Net Core

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-core-webapi, office-js, office-addins

Trying to consume web api method in Office Add-ins project Home.js file with ajax call, but api returns with error {"readyState":4,"status":200,"statusText":"load"} instead of actual api result with model list

```
**Web Api Method**
[HttpGet]
public IActionResult GetDocuments()
{
    List<DocumentLibrary> list = _context.DocumentLibraries.ToList();
    return new JsonResult(list);
}

**ajax call in Office Add-ins Home.js**
function makeAjaxCall() {
    Word.run(function (context) {

        $.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            url: 'https://localhost:7200/api/GetDocuments',
            dataType: "JSONP",
            success: function (response) {
                var doc = context.document.body;
                doc.insertText(JSON.stringify(response), Word.InsertLocation.start);
                showNotification("Success", JSON.stringify(response));
                return context.sync();
            },
            error: function (error) {
                showNotification("error", JSON.stringify(error));
            }
        });
    })
        .catch(errorHandler);
}
```

Comment: It looks like your web API is GetDocuments, but your ajax call URL is to "DocumentProcess". Try replacing "DocumentProcess" with "GetDocuments".

Comment: @RickKirkham the same issue still exists

Comment: Put a breakpoint on the line `return new JsonResult(list);`. What is the content of `list`?